# Find users coordinates with Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, geolocation, core-location

I am working on a project where i need to use the users location. I have tried to do this but many of the tutorials online are not working for me.

I have added the info.plist "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description" and have added the Build phrase "CoreLocation".

I have also tried the code-

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class CloseBeaches: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


let manager = CLLocationManager()

var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    print("Working")
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


}
```

But nothing ends up printing.

Is there a way that i can easily find the users coordinates and print them.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Change the `didUpdateLocations` to the Swift 3 one and you all set to go means simply add `_` as first parameter label to the delegate method.

Comment: Still isn't working @NiravD

Comment: Sam edit your question with new code also add the delegate method of error one and check may be that one is called